# Want to pass header field through rest api in windows phone application

Tags: c#, rest, windows-phone-8.1

I am having a issue in solving REST api call in windows phone application. 
The situation is something : 
I want to Pass two parameter named here "session_token" and "userid" as header in rest api call i am using the following code but the expected output is not matched with the postman out put (attached in screen shot)

I have the following code

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Connection);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-ype", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("session_token", "sdfsffsdfsdffsfsdfsdfsdfsdf");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("userid", "sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdd");

    var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("changepasswordinput", "{\"oldpassword\":\"sdfsdfdf\",\"newpassword\":\"sdfsdfsdf\"}"));
    HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);


    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("changepassword", content);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var outputstring = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        responseBaseClass = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ResponseBaseClass>();
    }
}
```

[image: Chrome Postman Screenshot1]

[image: Chrome Postman Screenshot1]

Please tell me where i am doing wrong. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right, the headers are there. Just click on the Headers(2) tab in Postman on the first screenshot and you will see them.

Comment: I have attached the Headers(2) tab screenshot. Actually my code is not giving the same output as in the postman

Comment: So what is the problem? You want those 2 headers to be sent and they are.

Comment: I am saying that the postman giving write answer but when i am running it from the code which described above is giving another output "Session token is missing". This is the problem.It should come the same output as postman.